# Не срабатывает opacity и visibility при focus

Tags: html, css

```css
.text-about__text_hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.text-about__readmore:focus .text-about__text_hidden {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-about">
    <div class="text-about__text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br />
        consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
        Vestibulum ultrices fi......
    </div>
    <div class="text-about__readmore">Read More
        <div class="text-about__text text-about__text_hidden">
            erat, eget laoreet justo elementum<br />
            et. Integer id nisl nibh. Fusce lacinia<br />
            iaculis tortor et fringilla.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при фокусе на элемент "`text-about__readmore`" "`Read More`" исчезало, а вместо него показывался скрытый текст, таким образом как у меня не получается добится хотя бы появления текста при фокусировке

Comment: если какой-то из ответов помог - отметьте его галочкой слева от ответа

Comment: См: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

по умолчанию div-ы не фокусируются. Но если добавить тегу атрибут `tabindex="-1"`, то всё получится.

```css
.text-about__text_hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.text-about__readmore:focus .text-about__text_hidden {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-about">
  <div class="text-about__text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> consectetur adipiscing elit.<br /> Vestibulum ultrices fi......
  </div>
  <div class="text-about__readmore" tabindex="-1">Read More
    <div class="text-about__text text-about__text_hidden">
      erat, eget laoreet justo elementum<br /> et. Integer id nisl nibh. Fusce lacinia<br /> iaculis tortor et fringilla.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я, оказывается, о такой штуке не знал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто.

`:focus` применяется для выделения `input`'ов в форме в тот момент, когда им передано управления, то есть когда они выделены и на них стоит курсор.
Это не тот "фокус", о котором вы подумали.

А в вашем случае нужно использовать `:hover`
Он срабатывает когда курсор находится над объектом

```css
.text-about__text_hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.text-about__readmore:hover .text-about__text_hidden {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-about">
    <div class="text-about__text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br />
        consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
        Vestibulum ultrices fi......
    </div>
    <div class="text-about__readmore">Read More
        <div class="text-about__text text-about__text_hidden">
            erat, eget laoreet justo elementum<br />
            et. Integer id nisl nibh. Fusce lacinia<br />
            iaculis tortor et fringilla.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```